# High Pass Filter for image processing in python by using scipy/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, fft

I am currently studying image processing. In SciPy, I know there is a median filter in scipy.signal. Is there a filter similar to a high pass filter?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

"High pass filter" is a very generic term.  There are an infinite number of different "highpass filters" that do very different things (e.g. an edge dectection filter, as mentioned earlier, is technically a highpass (most are actually a bandpass) filter, but has a very different effect from what you probably had in mind.)

At any rate, based on most of the questions you've been asking, you should probably look into [`scipy.ndimage`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) instead of `scipy.filter`, especially if you're going to be working with large images (ndimage can preform operations in-place, conserving memory).

As a basic example, showing a few different ways of doing things:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import Image

def plot(data, title):
    plot.i += 1
    plt.subplot(2,2,plot.i)
    plt.imshow(data)
    plt.gray()
    plt.title(title)
plot.i = 0

# Load the data...
im = Image.open('lena.png')
data = np.array(im, dtype=float)
plot(data, 'Original')

# A very simple and very narrow highpass filter
kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],
                   [-1,  8, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1]])
highpass_3x3 = ndimage.convolve(data, kernel)
plot(highpass_3x3, 'Simple 3x3 Highpass')

# A slightly "wider", but sill very simple highpass filter 
kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
                   [-1,  1,  2,  1, -1],
                   [-1,  2,  4,  2, -1],
                   [-1,  1,  2,  1, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]])
highpass_5x5 = ndimage.convolve(data, kernel)
plot(highpass_5x5, 'Simple 5x5 Highpass')

# Another way of making a highpass filter is to simply subtract a lowpass
# filtered image from the original. Here, we'll use a simple gaussian filter
# to "blur" (i.e. a lowpass filter) the original.
lowpass = ndimage.gaussian_filter(data, 3)
gauss_highpass = data - lowpass
plot(gauss_highpass, r'Gaussian Highpass, $\sigma = 3 pixels$')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a great script! I learned a lot about convolve() and matplotlib *and* even Python.  (I had no idea something like "plot.i" could work.)

Comment: isn't a Gaussian filter a low pass filter?

Comment: @A.H. - Yes, but if you subtract the gaussian lowpass from the original image, you get an equivalent highpass filter.  That's what's referred to as a "gaussian high pass".  (Have a look at the comments above the code for that portion.)

Comment: Given the return of convolve, it's possible to get the dx and dy?

Answer (score 10):

Here is how we can design a HPF with `scipy fftpack`

```
from skimage.io import imread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fftpack as fp

im = np.mean(imread('../images/lena.jpg'), axis=2) # assuming an RGB image
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(im, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

**Original Image**

[image]

```
F1 = fftpack.fft2((im).astype(float))
F2 = fftpack.fftshift(F1)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow( (20*np.log10( 0.1 + F2)).astype(int), cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.show()
```

**Frequency Spectrum with FFT**

[image]

```
(w, h) = im.shape
half_w, half_h = int(w/2), int(h/2)

# high pass filter
n = 25
F2[half_w-n:half_w+n+1,half_h-n:half_h+n+1] = 0 # select all but the first 50x50 (low) frequencies
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow( (20*np.log10( 0.1 + F2)).astype(int))
plt.show()
```

**Block low Frequencies in the Spectrum**

[image]

```
im1 = fp.ifft2(fftpack.ifftshift(F2)).real
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(im1, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

**Output Image after applying the HPF**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One simple high-pass filter is:

```
-1 -1 -1
-1  8 -1
-1 -1 -1
```

The [Sobel operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) is another simple example.

In image processing these sorts of filters are often called "edge-detectors" - [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) was OK on this last time I checked.

Comment: True that the Laplace operator is often called an edge detector. Sad, really, because it isn’t. It is really good at detecting lines and dots, not so much edges (as in: it doesn’t give a high response at edges, it tends to be zero there).

Answer (score 1):

[scipy.filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) contains a large number of generic filters. Something like the [iirfilter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.iirdesign.html#scipy.signal.iirdesign) class can be configured to yield the typical Chebyshev or Buttworth digital or analog high pass filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Gaussian filter as it gives much sharpness than a pure HPF, for using a simple HPF you can use the following code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from scipy import ndimage

class HPF(object):
    def __init__(self, kernel, image):
        self.kernel = np.array(kernel)
        self.image = image

    def process(self):
        return ndimage.convolve(self.image, self.kernel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #enter ur image location
    image = cv2.imread("images/test2.jpg", 0)
    kernel3x3 = [[-1,-1,-1],[-1,8,-1],[-1,-1,-1]]
    kernel5x5 = [[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
    [-1, 1, 2, 1, -1],
    [-1, 2, 4, 2, -1],
    [-1, 1, 2, 1, -1],
    [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]

    hpf1 = HPF(kernel3x3, image)
    hpfimage1 = hpf1.process()
    hpf2 = HPF(kernel5x5, image)
    hpfimage2 = hpf2.process()
    cv2.imshow("3x3",hpfimage1)
    cv2.imshow("5x5",hpfimage2)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To use the Gaussian filter just add the Gaussian blur to your image

```
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (11, 11), 0)
```

Then minus it from the original image

```
g_hpf = image - blurred
```

Original code taken from : [Image Sharpening by High Pass Filter using Python and OpenCV](http://www.psychocodes.in/image-sharpening-by-high-pass-filter-using-python-and-opencv.html)