# Wrong Shape in Filter of Scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy, keras, loss-function

I am trying to scipy convolve function but it shows an error that there is wrong shape of filter.  I have a filter shape of `(1, 3, 3, 1)` and image shape of `(10,8,8,3)`

I found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34233642/scikit-image-gabor-filter-error-filter-weights-array-has-incorrect-shape) but it has one less dimension which is not true in my case.

Any idea, how could I resolve this?

Sample Code :

```
from scipy import ndimage
img1.shape : (10,8,8,3)
downsample_filter.shape : (1, 3, 3, 1)
filtered_im1 = ndimage.filters.convolve(img1, downsample_filter, 
                                                mode='reflect')
```

> **Solution**:
>   I have resolved the error by converting both variables into numpy. It can be done by passing a placeholder and image into `sess.run()` so that we could get the numpy array.

But, I am interested to solve this issue using Tensors as I cannot use the above method in **Keras Loss Function** for `y_pred` & `y_true`

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question.  Scipy has more than one convolution function, and there is also one in numpy.  To help you, we need to see the code that generates the error.

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: Thanks.  If I create an example based on what you have shown, it works with no errors.  Can you create a small, *runnable* example that demonstrates the error?  For example, I did `img1 = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(10, 8, 8, 3))`, etc.

Comment: That's the problem. It should work but it doesn't. 

Actually, I'm working on Keras, so, When I checked their datatype, filter is of numpy whereas other-one is Tensor. I converted the filter into tensorflow as well but I faced another error i.e. cannot combine with a sequence.

Comment: Error: 

`setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: Can you convert all the arguments to numpy arrays?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to do that but couldn't found yet.

Comment: Consider changing one of the question tags to `tensorflow`.  Then the question might catch the attention of some tensorflow gurus.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE while reading the image.

```
 cv2.imread("yourImage.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
 OR
 cv2.imread("yourImage.jpg",0) #loading graysclae image
```