# Applying a specific High pass filter on a RGB image in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, image-preprocessing

I'm trying to preproccess my image before feeding it to the CNN.

**Goal**

To extract the residual after applying a high pass filter( Reference 1 ) on a RGB image of dimensions 512x512 ( basically a shape of (512,512, 3) ) using the following equation:

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Cb5.png)

where *I* is the Image and the matrix is the high pass filter.

Initially, I thought of approaching the problem by using approach defined in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094957/high-pass-filter-for-image-processing-in-python-by-using-scipy-numpy).
But they used a Grayscale image.

**Hypothesis**:

Separate the image in different channels and then apply the filter to channel before combining them again.

Do you think that this is the right way to solve the problem or is there any better approach?
And how would I go about this in Python?

**Reference**:

1) [Deep Learning for steganalysis via convolutional neural networks](http://7xsbsy.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/Deep%20learning%20for%20steganalysis%20via%20convolutional%20neural%20networks.pdf)

2) [Camera Model Identification With the use of Deep CNN's](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7823908/)

**Update**
Currently, this is my function for the high pass filter:

```
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np

def high_pass(data):
    kernel = [[-1, 2, -2, 2, -1],
              [2, -6, 8, -6, 2],
              [-2, 8, -12, 8, -2],
              [2, -6, 8, -6, 2],
              [-1, 2, -2, 2, -1]]
    kernel = np.dstack([kernel, kernel, kernel]) * (1.0/12.0)
    residual = ndimage.convolve(data, kernel)

    return residual
```

Comment: What is the problem/question statement here? Is your current code not working? Also could you not map the RGB to Grayscale, filter, then remap to RGB?

Comment: The current code works but I'm not sure if that's the right way to apply a high pass filter.

Comment: I'm not exactly certain what your kernel is doing. Off of the top of my head it looks like it is removing texturing from the image. There isn't much documentation on it in the papers you attached. It is different from a typical HPF. The standard basic approach in image processing is to treat each channel separately with the filter as you have done and then recombine the channels after processing. So yes your current method is valid. There are more advanced methods which rely on looking at gradients in higher dimensional color space that you may want to look at as well.

Comment: Why do you want to use a high pass filter? You might be better off filtering in HSV instead of RGB, maybe just filter the H channel. But isn't the point of DNNs that they learn the preprocessing for you? Can't the CNN can just learn how to filter high frequencies if needed.

Comment: I didn't think of filtering HSV. Yes, the DNNs are meant to learn the preprocessing itself but in the paper, they had implemented it as such.
I was trying to get similar results with my dataset.